# What could be reason CDI on Java EE not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-8

I added  in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And normally CDI should just be provided by this dependency.

I deploy my war on a Payara micro server.

But all the @Inject annotations are not working.
All the objects are still null.

For example I have this class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class GreetingService {

    public String getGreetingTemplate(String language) {
        String result = "Hello %s";
        switch (language) {
        case "fr":
            result = "Bonjour %s";
            break;
        case "de":
            result = "Willkommen, %s";
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then I do

```
@Stateless
public class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {

    @Inject
    private GreetingService greetingService;
      :
```

Whatever I do greetingService always is null.
I have beans.xml even I read since Java EE 7 it is no longer required.
I even set it to  bean-discovery-mode="all"  .

It already gives me headache. I really have not a single clue.

Comment: Where is MyClassImpl called from and how? It is already being injected by CDI?

Comment: I made MyClassImpl  also be  injected in a Controller. It turns out it is also null. Seems CDI is not working across whole application  . javax.inject.Inject  is the namespace

Comment: Which Payara version are you using? Which flavour? I have created a dummy project and deploy in payara and it is working as expected. Can you provide your actual code? And pom?

Answer (score 0):

try to add a beans.xml to your project with property: bean-discovery-mode="all"